# solving existence problems in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, problem-solving

i'm here to ask for some tips/books,writes or anything that helps to solve a specifically type of problem:to prove that exists something in measure theory.
Even more specifically, i am stuck in chapter 9 of bartle's book (measure theory and integration) because there are a lot of these problems and altough i had seem(and understand) some solutions, i just cant formulate one by myself.
The exercise 9.G ,for example, say:
If A is a Lebesgue measurable subset of R and $\epsilon > 0$, show that
there exists an open set $G_{\epsilon} \supseteq A$ such that
$l^{*}(A) < l^{*}(G_{\epsilon}) < l^{*}(A) + \epsilon$
I just write the hypotesis and what they implie, but everytime i try to go any further i never get anything closer to a concrete case.
The thing is that this happens to almost every question of this kind(show existence), the other ones i dont have this much trouble.
If someone can help i would really apreciate, its really frustating. The other questions at least after some more study i am able to solve in general, but not this ones.

Comment: there is no general trick to solve existence proofs, because the topic is too broad. To solve an exercise some times you will need to re-read various past chapters of a book, to search for theorems, lemmas or corollaries that you had forgotten. In this particular case the problem is a corollary of the definition of the outer Lebesgue measure

Comment: My tip would be to make the problem a little simpler, and then see if you can extend your argument. For your example, first try it for the closed interval $[0,1]$. You'll notice this example is probably too simple to extend to arbitrary $A$. How about the rationals? There's a standard trick here which uses that the rationals are countable and the sum $\sum 2^{-i}$ converges. That seems like a useful trick which you might be able to extend. But what about uncountable sets $A$? Maybe you just need to find a dense countable subset? No that's not quite right because..., but maybe..., etc., etc.